# Make a DIV as a centred focal point on the page

Tags: html, css

I want to have a login form centred on the page.  An example is [here](https://app.onehub.com/login)

I know how to centre an element what I can't work out is how to centre an element always in the centre of the page even if the browser window changes size

Comment: Do you know about the auto property for margins? This gives you flexible margins, which you can use in other contexts too.

Comment: What's great about the given example (onehub) is that it uses a method not described in any solutions (yet...).  They used CSS to set the div's display property to mimic that of a table. This method is controversial though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic problem. Here's some example CSS:

```
#your_element{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Important bit: the negative margins should be half of the respective dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed;` to it's style. If you know how to center it, then just adding this should do the trick.

Have a look here for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position

Answer (score 0):

I keep this template HTML just for this situation, when I need a container that is vertically and horizontally centered:

CSS:

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        background: #ffc;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #vertical-center {
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -185px;
    }

    #content {
        background: #ffffde;
        border: 2px dashed red;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 350px;
        width: 500px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="vertical-center"></div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Centered Content</h1>
    <p>This content is centered on the page.</p>
    <p>More importantly, it won't get cut off when the browser window becomes too small to display it.</p>
</div>
```

Note that the #vertical-center has a margin-top that has to be half the height of the #content div, and it has to be negative.